# allocation of bidimensional array of chars in c

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, allocation

I have a struct that contains a grid, then a bidimensional array of chars, because I need to simulate a game where each player can put 'o' or 'x' in each cell.
My structure is the following one (I implemented it following an answer in this website):

```
 struct game {
     char ** grid;

 };
```

Now in my function create_game, I tried to implemented it as follow:

```
struct game *create(int columns, int rows)
{
    struct game *new_game = malloc(sizeof(struct game));
    if (new_game)
    {

        new_game->grid = malloc(sizeof(char) * rows);
        if (new_game->grid == NULL)
        {
            free(new_game);
            return NULL;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            new_game->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);
            // set each cell to empty string
            if (new_game->grid[i] == NULL)
            {
                free(new_game->grid);
                free(new_game);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < new_game->rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < new_game->columns; j++)
            {
                new_game->grid[i][j] = ' ';
                printf("%c ", new_game->grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return new_game;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work because it returns the error segmentation fault. How can I create a grid of chars? Or I have to create an array of strings because I cannot have chars on a row but I need to append them creating a string?

Comment: The code you have provided won't compile, because there are 'missing' members in your `struct game` definition.

Comment: However, with that fixed, your first `malloc` call is wrong: change `new_game->grid = malloc(sizeof(char) * rows);` to `new_game->grid = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);`, because you want an array of pointers for that, not an array of `char`.

Comment: Why I need an array of pointers?

Comment: @Elena there are a few ways to do a 2D array.  In the way suggested above, you make a 1D array of pointers that each point to a 1D array of cells.  When using an array of this type, you can use `grid[a][b]`, to retrieve a char.  Looking a little deeper, `grid[a]` returns a pointer of type `char *` which is then dereferenced using index `[b]` to select a char.  That's why `grid` is declared as a `char **` ... a pointer to an array of pointers in this case.

Comment: A second manual way would be to say `char *grid = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof char)` --- that is, a 1D array large enough for all the cells --- and then manually index into it as `grid[row * rowsize + col]` where rowsize is the number of elements in a row.

Comment: Finally, a third way would be to declare one dimension of the array in the pointer type: `char (*grid) [rowsize] = malloc(sizeof (char[row_size]) * num_rows)` but this would you to know one of the dimensions to be constant, at least for some revisions of the C language.  This last one is also used as `grid[a][b]`, but in this case, the type of `grid[a]` is an array-type, `char[row_size]`, and not a pointer.